Two teenage girls set out to prove that their principal is a murderer
I can't remember the name of this movie but it's based around two teenage girls who live close to each other and communicate through walkie talkies when at their own homes. I think one is called Jane. Their school gets a new principal and one suspects he is a murderer. I remember one scene where they're in his house searching and finds muddy golf shoes and what looks like blood. The principal knows in the end that he's caught and kidnaps one of the girls. I can remember Jane (I think) made him crash into a tree at the golf course, saving her friend who was tied up in his boot.


Frog and Wombat (1998)

From her bedroom window, Alli (code name "Frog") thinks that she has
  discovered the cover up of a serious crime. She is convinced that her
  new school principal has committed a murder, and she is going to prove
  it! When her best friend, Jane (code name "Wombat"), rejects this
  idea, a brazen Frog decides to set up surveillance, collect some
  evidence and break the case.

From this review, a few more details:

Allison Parker likes to imagine herself something of a detective,
  keeping tabs on what goes on in her neighborhood and communicating
  with her best friend Jane Walker via walkie talkie.
[...]
However, when the girl's new principal, Larry Struble, moves in next
  door, Allison begins to wonder if she might have a real mystery to
  investigate when Larry's niece Nancy disappears a few days after he's
  moved in.

A few screenshots from the movie:



Read more about it here and browse through the rest of the screenshots here.
Watch the trailer here.
